# Curl error (56): Failure when receiving data from the peer

Tags: centos, dnf

Now I want to update my operation system like this:

```
dnf udpate
```

but shows this error:

```
Total download size: 69 M
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Downloading Packages:

    The downloaded packages were saved in cache until the next successful transaction.
    You can remove cached packages by executing 'dnf clean packages'.
    Error: Error downloading packages:
      Curl error (56): Failure when receiving data from the peer for http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=7&arch=x86_64&repo=os&infra=$infra [Recv failure: Connection reset by peer]
```

when I ping the domain using this command:

```
[root@izbp19pke6x0v6ruecuy1yz .acme.sh]# ping mirrorlist.centos.org
PING mirrorlist.centos.org (147.75.69.225) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from packet04.centos.org (147.75.69.225): icmp_seq=1 ttl=47 time=259 ms
64 bytes from packet04.centos.org (147.75.69.225): icmp_seq=2 ttl=47 time=259 ms
64 bytes from packet04.centos.org (147.75.69.225): icmp_seq=3 ttl=47 time=259 ms
^C
--- mirrorlist.centos.org ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2001ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 259.591/259.672/259.786/0.594 ms
```

the ping tell me the domain accessable. why the curl tell that error? I am searching from internet but no one talk about this problem. what should I do to avoid this error?

Comment: The last component of the URL `infra=$infra` doesn't look correct. What's in your repofiles? Also, this bug seems related, although it's about Centos 8: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1920735

Comment: @berndbausch the guys uses an extremely outdated CentOS, his curl fails because his libraries and ca-certificates are terribly outdated. Check this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/657915/could-not-get-nonce-lets-try-again-when-using-acme and his questions history. It's now the 6th question where he complains his curl doesn't work. It's getting tiresome really.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Yes but he is trying to upgrade. Dolphin: Rather than using a mirror list, try pointing directly to a repo in your vicinity. You may have to use vault.centos.org for retired repos. Also, I would first test this in a virtual machine or so before you mess up your server, which (judging from other questions) seems to run several critical applications.